# How to add Delete DDL statement through variable in SSDT

Tags: sql-server-data-tools, ssas-tabular, ssdt-2017

I want to delete partitions for specific date via delete DDL statements using variables in SSDT.

Currently getting error as "Invalid input"

I tried with direct input option also, but it doesn't work.

Below code works fine when static date is passed as directinput:

```
{
  "delete" : {
   "object" : {
          "database": "TestDatabase",
          "Table" : "Delta",
          "partition" : "Delta 20200501" 
     }
   }
}
```

I tried with passing variable to the date, but it doesn't work:

```
{
      "delete" : {
       "object" : {
              "database": "TestDatabase",
              "Table" : "Delta",
              "partition" : "Delta " + REPLACE(@[USER::ExpiryDate],"-",""), + " \"
         }
       }
    }
```

what is the exact delete syntax for deleting partition and how can I use a variable instead of static date?

Thank you

Comment: why do you want to do that via variable? normally it is done with post scripts

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev- to automate the process. I want to create a variable of delete code and use it. I have modified my question, please check